# \Filter\Interceptor getting added to end of argument class in plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin, elasticsearch

I am attempting to create a plugin for an extension but when it runs I get a 500 error stating the argument I'm passing is incorrect, here is my code:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection as ProductCollection;

class FilterPlugin
{
    public function beforePrepareCollection(\Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection $collection)
    {

        $collection->addFieldToFilter('category_ids', 11);
    }
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Module\Plugin\FilterPlugin::beforePrepareCollection() must be an instance of Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection, instance of Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Autocomplete\Product\Collection\Filter\Interceptor given, called in /home/<user>/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146 and defined in /home/<user>/public_html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/FilterPlugin.php:12 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/<user>/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Vendor\Module\Plugin\FilterPlugin->afterPrepareCollection(Object(Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Autocomplete\Product\Collection\Filter\Interceptor), Object(Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor), Object(Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor)) 
#1 /home/<user>/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/In in /home/<user>/public_html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/FilterPlugin.php on line 12
```

I have cleared /generated/code and ran bin/magento setup:di:compile with no luck.
it appears to be passing an object of Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Autocomplete\Product\Collection\Filter\Intercept
instead of Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Autocomplete\Product\Collection

Any help would be appreciated.

As asked here is my di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\Autocomplete\Product\Collection\Filter">
        <plugin name="Vendor_GenderFilterToSearch" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\FilterPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Please share your XML code

Comment: Share your di.XML code which will help to make parameter formation correct in your after method. However the argument format you passed is not the exact way kershrew for after plugin

Comment: I have added my di.xml and changed the method to a before as this is how I wanted it in the first place, it was after for me to test if that helped in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own fault with the plugin, I mis-read the docs and assumed that $subject was the title getting set in their example. $subject needs to be an object of the one your applying the filter to, adding that correct first argument to my method has made it work fine.

What a fool I am.